# JSF and primefaces suggestions in vscode

Tags: jsf, primefaces, visual-studio-code

How can I get suggestions/autocomplete for JSF syntax and primefaces components in VScode?

I'm developing a java web application and trying to migrate my working environment, from eclipse to vscode. It's been quicker to operate mvn, do deploys and writing .java files. But I couldn't find a solution for autocompleting JSF and primefaces components syntax in .xhtml files.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: _It's been quicker to operate mvn, do deploys and writing .java files. _ Hard to believe, but for the jsf/primefaces part I think you have to call microsoft

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already an extension to autocomplete the syntax of primefaces components in .xhtml, .jsp, jsf,... files.

IntelliSense for PrimeFaces: "A Visual Studio Code extension that provides PrimeFaces component completion for the HTML, XHTML, JSP and JSF attribute based on the official Primefaces taglib definitions."

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=leosj29.jsf-primefaces-intellisense

Comment: It does not support PrimeFaces 12

Comment: Hello, you can open an issue in the git repository for support [https://github.com/leosj29/jsf-primefaces-intellisense](https://github.com/leosj29/jsf-primefaces-intellisense)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately currently there is no extension for Visual Studio Code JSF. Try using netBeans, Eclipse, or IntelliJ IDEA (Ultimate Edition).