# How do I configure JSF Project in vscode?

Tags: java, jsp, visual-studio-code, jsf

I am trying to setup things for JSF Project in VSCode, but I don't know how to do it, because wherever I check there are Maven (something) specific configurations. I am new to Java, so I don't even know what Maven is. Although I have successfully setup JSP Project in VSCode. So, I just think there must be a way to work with JSF as well in VSCode. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSF and primefaces suggestions in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57377209/jsf-and-primefaces-suggestions-in-vscode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I've posted this question, and Someone has upvoted it. So, I would like to Post the Solution that worked for me.

I just added `javax.faces.jar` file's path in CLASSPATH to Compile my application and also added that jar file inside of Apache's lib directory to run my application. and that worked for me. Also, for `xhtml` files you'll get built-in syntax highlighting but for Intellisense I think you'll have to find an extension.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it has no related extension of JSF in the VSCode for now.

Comment: Yeah but I am not necessarily looking for an Extension. I have setup JSP Project in VSCode, By Adding JAR files (required for JSP) in CLASSPATH and also in Apache Tomcat - LIB directory. So is there anyway I can Achieve same with JSF ?

Answer (score 0):

For `.xhtml` syntax highlighting and autocomplete, add the "JSF Primefaces Intellisense" plugin.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

There is already an extension to meet your requirement, you can refer to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71886667/11887174).